# Calculate R-squared with JAGS and R

Tags: r, bayesian, goodness-of-fit, jags

I have the following model that I am running in JAGS from R:

```
 model {
        for( i in 1:nData){
          y[i] ~ dnorm(mu[i], tau)
          mu[i] <- b0 + inprod(b[],x[i,])              
          }

        tau ~ dgamma(.01,.01)
        b0 ~ dnorm(0,.0001)
        for (j in 1:nPredictors){
          b[j] ~ dgamma(2,2)
          }
        }
```

It is a simple regression model with a gamma prior on the beta coefficients. I can run the model and get some reasonable results, but my boss wants to know whether the Bayesian flavor is better than a normal OLS regression, and to this end he wants me to calculate an R^2 statistic for both models. I am fairly new to Bayesian statistics, so if anyone could share some R code to illustrate how it is done, I would be very grateful!

Comment: If you could share a fragment of your R code, at least the part that calls JAGS, that would help construct some R code that would address your "how it is done" question in the context of your code, as there are several ways you could be doing this.

Comment: Thomas, 1) why do you use `dgamma` prior - it doesn't allow negative values of your linear coefficients, are you aware of it? It is not a standard linear regression then. 2) Why do you use `inprod` instead of classic full formula with `+` and `*` - is it faster in JAGS? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can do this.  The first would be to use the mean of the posterior for each of the $\mu_i$, and calculate a residual using this as the "estimated value" corresponding to $\hat{\beta}X$ in OLS.  You then calculate the variance of the residuals as usual and plug it into the $R^2$ calculation.  You would do this in R, of course.  An alternative would be to use the posterior mean of the variance ($1/\tau$) as the estimate of residual variance in the $R^2$ calculation, again done in R.  The former comes closest to how $R^2$ is calculated in classical statistics.

No doubt there are other approaches, which (hopefully) others will point out in their answers.

However, the bigger issues are a) with $R^2$ as a criterion and b) with comparison of OLS estimation to anything else using $R^2$ as a criterion.  I'll skip over the first, pointing you to [statisticalengineering.com](http://www.statisticalengineering.com/r-squared.htm) and [Andrew Gelman](http://andrewgelman.com/2007/08/rsquared_useful/) as references.  The second issue arises because OLS maximizes $R^2$ (a consequence of the "least squares" property) and therefore no other technique (that is not equivalent to OLS) will generate as high an $R^2$.  Consequently, your Bayesian approach is doomed if maximizing $R^2$ is the criterion of choice.

You might be able to suggest a more out-of-sample criterion instead, for example, a k-fold [cross-validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29), which would necessitate multiple runs of JAGS on subsets of the data, then comparing the out-of-sample predicted values to the actual values.  You can generate the predicted values inside JAGS as observed in the answer to [Missing values in response variable in JAGS](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22184/missing-values-in-response-variable-in-jags), or in R of course.

I'll also point out that the `dgamma(0.01,0.01)` distribution has largely fallen out of favor, as it is actually quite informative near zero.  The answers to [priors for lognormal models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30369/priors-for-log-normal-models/30381#30381) might help with that.